# SQL Query returning same value while using where 1 condition

Tags: sql-server, query

I have created a temp table and inserted the values as given below.

```sql
create table #temp( val int );

insert into #temp values(333);
insert into #temp values(222);
insert into #temp values(111);
```

On querying the below select statement I got 333 as the answer.

```sql
Select * 
from #temp a 
Where 1 =(
    Select COUNT(VAL) 
    from #temp b 
    where a.val <= b.val
);
```

**Result:**

```
val

333
```

Can you please help me understand how SQL server came to this solution.

Comment: SQL server returned exactly what you requested. What is your expected result?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, Can you please explain how did query return 333?

Comment: You ask server to find the record for which there exists only one record with the value of `val` equal or greater (so this 'only one' is this record itself) if it is alone (count=1, not duplicated). And you obtain strictly the record which matches this conditions. Why you're surprised?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite your query such a way:

```
SELECT a.*, x.cnt
FROM #temp a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(VAL) AS cnt
    FROM #temp b
    WHERE a.val <= b.val
) x
--WHERE x.cnt = 1
```

If you uncomment the where clause you would get `333 | 1` as a result. You request a row from the outer table which doesn't have duplicates or bigger values.

Answer (score 3):

You could see your inner count query

```
Select COUNT(VAL) from #temp b  
where a.val <= b.val;
```

as

```
(Select COUNT(VAL) from #temp b  
where 333 <= 333,222,111) = 1


(Select COUNT(VAL) from #temp b  
where 222 <= 333,222,111) = 2


(Select COUNT(VAL) from #temp b  
where 111 <= 333,222,111) = 3
```

Showing that only `333` from `#temp a` has one match, as it has only one *equals to or smaller than* match with the 3 values in `#temp b`.

This returns a count of `1` and is why the value `333` from `#temp a` is returned.